# Div changes depending on a <select> menu

Tags: javascript, select, menu

I'm trying to do something similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/JSyLV/1/

But I can't get that code to work in dreamweaver, simply from copy and paste.

I put the javascript code in my header using  and

and directly copied the html to my body, but all the divs show and its not applying the javascript to the drop down menu. Am I implementing the javascript code incorrectly?

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>TEST</title>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.group').hide();
    $('#option1').show();
    $('#selectMe').change(function () {
        $('.group').hide();
        $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
    })
});
</script>

</head>


<body>

<div id="option1" class="group">asdf</div>
<div id="option2" class="group">kljh</div>
<div id="option3" class="group">zxcv</div>
<div id="option4" class="group">qwerty</div>
    <select id="selectMe">
        <option value="option1">option1</option>
        <option value="option2">option2</option>
        <option value="option3">option3</option>
        <option value="option4">option4</option>
    </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'll need to provide more details - the JS looks good on the fiddle..  Any errors in the JS console?

Comment: I suggest not using dreamweaver.  From personal experience, not many people like it, and it seems to cause lots of problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more likely that you got JQuery loaded incorrectly into your dreamweaver project. A quick fix would be to add this in the header before the first script tag :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Which leads to : http://pastebin.com/gtLyVcU2

Comment: I have added this but there's no change.

Comment: I just updated my answer and tested it on my end, it works only if you get jquery loaded before using the "$" selector. (added the "http" thing before the URL, this will help I think ^^)

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.group').hide();
$('#option1').show();
$('#selectMe').change(function () {
    $('.group').hide();
    $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
})
});

}); 

</script>

<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 2</title>


</head>
<body>
<div id="option1" class="group">asdf</div>
<div id="option2" class="group">kljh</div>
<div id="option3" class="group">zxcv</div>
<div id="option4" class="group">qwerty</div>
<select id="selectMe">
<option value="option1">option1</option>
<option value="option2">option2</option>
<option value="option3">option3</option>
<option value="option4">option4</option>
</select>


</body>

</html>
```